# floating value not being shown up correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum

im building a shopping cart for an application and im trying to get the total value of the sum between all the elements with the class ".totalPrice".

everything is working fine and the sum is being done correctly untill i try to sum values like 1.005.67 + 1.050.00, then the result is printed like this

[image]

this is my code:

```js
function sum() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.totalPrice').each(function () {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
  });
  $("#total").text("Total: $" + sum.toFixed(2).replace(".",","));        
}
```

```html
<label>
<label> Value 1 </label>
<input type="text" class="totalPrice">
<br><br><br>
<label> Value 2 </label>
<input type="text" class="totalPrice">
<br><br><br>
<button onclick="sum()"> calculate </button>
<h1 id="total"> </h1> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You appear to be giving `parseFloat` a value with two decimal separators. It'll ignore the second one and everything after it, i.e. `1.005.67` will be treated as `1.005` and `1.050.00` will be treated as `1.050`. `parseFloat('1.005') + parseFloat('1.050')` -> `2.0549999999999997`. `2.0549999999999997.toFixed(2)` -> `2.05`.

Comment: I have never seen notation that looks like `1.005.67`. What number is that supposed to represent? Are you sure you didn't mean `1,005.67`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there are two decimal places within your inputs.

When you run `parseFloat("1.005.67")`, you get 1.005; and, from `parseFloat("1.050.00"), you get 1.05.

Adding these numbers together, you get 2.055, which you're then rounding to 2 decimal places, hence the result $2.05.

For the number to parse as you expect, the inputs must have only one decimal point.

Comment: `2.055.toFixed(2)` -> `2.06`.

Comment: thanks man, i think i figured it out, i was returning the value from my database with a mask to format the value, i removed this mask and began to bring the raw value from the database. now, when im showing the value on screen, i just used .toFixed(2) on the var "sum" and everythings apparently working just fine. appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of `Intl.NumberFormat` and set it to `currency`.

Please, name variables appropriately. Do not have a variable and function with identical names. It is confusing for the reader.

**Noe:** If you set your `<input>` to `type="number"`, you can set the `step` to account for 1/100ths and you can now grab the input value without parsing, with `input.valueAsNumber`.

```js
const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US',
  { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });

const calculateSumAndDisplay = () => {
  const sum = [...document.querySelectorAll('.totalPrice')]
    .reduce((total, input) => total + input.valueAsNumber, 0);
  document.querySelector('#total')
    .textContent = `Total: ${currencyFormatter.format(sum)}`;        
}
```

```html
<label>Value 1</label>
<input type="number" class="totalPrice" step="0.01" />
<br>
<label>Value 2</label>
<input type="number" class="totalPrice" step="0.01" />
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="calculateSumAndDisplay()">Calculate</button>
<h1 id="total"></h1>
```